# React JS isomorphic render

Tags: node.js, reactjs, socket.io, flux, isomorphic-javascript

ReactJS, original Flux, react-router, nodeJS, socket.io
Everything is up to date.

If i'm switching off javascript in browser, only static code is being rendered.

During server side render `ComponentWillMount` and `render` methods being fired up, but not `ComponentDidMount`.
Even if I'm putting Flux logic into `ComponentWillMount` method, nothing happen: action is called, but socket.io doesn't send request to server to get data from database. Which means, no data being retrieved from database and nothing useful for search engines is being rendered.
If javascript is enabled, everything works perfect.

Here the important pieces of code:

Component. Add listener and call action:

```
componentDidMount() {
    StoreUser.addChangeListener(this._onChange);
    Actions.getUser(this.props.params.userid)   
}
```

Client's action asks server for user data:

```
function _getUser (userid) {
  socket.emit('getUser', userid)
}
```

up until this place server-side rendering works, but server itself doesn't received `getUser` event, so nothing happens further.
Again, if javascript is enabled in browser, all this works fine. Server receives this call and returns user's data.

How do i make server receive this event, return user's data and render it before sending to client?
As alternative, may be there is different way to make it SEO friendly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

React's `componentDidMount` lifecycle hook is not called server-side, [as stated in the docs](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#mounting-componentdidmount).

If you need to fetch data and use it server-side in the `render` method of a component, you need to pass this data as `props` during the initial render. This means, you cannot fetch it either during `componentWillMount`, even if the hook is called.

To achieve what you want, you need your server-side code to:

- determine what components will be rendered
- dispatch the proper actions so that your store will be properly populated
- render your components only then - as the data is available to pass to your components in an initial render

The details on how to achieve that would of course depend on your flux implementation, the framework you use server-side, etc.

Comment: is there simpler way to make it seo-friendly?)

Comment: well the only other way would be to not use React's server-side render functionality and to render your website pages in a headless browser (something like phantom.js), cache the resulting html, and respond that server-side. If you don't want to implement this yourself, some cloud services exist to do that. http://www.analog-ni.co/precomposing-a-spa-may-become-the-holy-grail-to-seo

Comment: As a side note, the React way is not that complicated, it all depends on your flux implementation. Redux, for example, makes it pretty straight-forward.

Comment: Then you can instantiate a flux store per request, add static `fetchData` methods to your components, after the `ReactRouter.match` call, you can inspect the `renderProps.components` and call their `fetchData` method if any with `renderProps.params`, then only, you can render your React component